# AWS Appsync subscription is not updating my component

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync

I've cloned a repo from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-an-app-with-graphql-react-native-and-aws-appsync-the-app--cms-30569) and trying to explore AWS AppSync's subscription. My understanding is that if there is real-time updates to server data, client should expect to see some notification or updates or sorts, so what I did was:

1. running the app on a simulator
2. Open DynamoDB console and add the records manually.

I was expecting there is some notifications received on my app but there isn't, and if I refresh the app it will have the updated records? Am I understand the subscription wrongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscriptions are not triggered from your dynamo db, but from your mutations (defined in your graphql schema). Try to add records via the mutation your subscription listens on. You can run a mutation from the app sync console under "queries".

If your client is set up correctly, it should update accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Subscription can only be triggered by mutation. When you add record directly to your DB, the mutation is not called hence no subscription is triggered. Does not really servers the purpose for the external db updates. There is work around available.
Scenario 1: If you are making the change to the DB directly via some DB client, you need to call the mutation endpoint explicitly (from AWS console, postman etc.). This will trigger the subscription. I am guessing the direct DB change is done for testing.

Scenario 2: The direct DB change is done by some other external process and not via Appsync mutation. You need to call the none data source mapped mutation in your processor. This dummy mutation will trigger the subscription.
Here's [a link] (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/appsync-notify-subscribers-real-time/  ) explaining how to create a none data source mapped mutation.